# What is the correct way for updating a Svelte writable array store?

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

What is the correct way (or differences if both are correct) for updating a `$orderItems = writable([])` Svelte writable array store? We'll assume `result` is a new item I want to push at the end of `$orderItems`.

```html
orderItems.update(items => ([...items, result]))
```

or

```html
$orderItems = [...$orderItems, result]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both are correct and another alternative would be

```
$orderItems.push(result)
$orderItems = $orderItems
```

and

```
orderItems.update(items => {
    items.push(result)
    return items
})
```

The difference is that the `$` syntax can only be used inside components, so `.svelte` files. From [the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values)

> Any time you have a reference to a store, you can access its value **inside a component** by prefixing it with the $ character. This causes Svelte to declare the prefixed variable, subscribe to the store at component initialization and unsubscribe when appropriate.

If you want to modify the store from a `.js` file, this can only be done via `.set() / .update()`

Answer (score 0):

Even easier (with just one assignment):

```
$orderItems[$orderItems.length] = result
```